# Can we use imagemagick Library in android?

Tags: android, imagemagick, jmagick

But there is only Jmagick JAVA interface Provided in imagemagick website? Can we make that java library to include in android ? Using NDK is not preferred as Memory leaks may occur.And the code in github using ndk is not fully completed. If there is no way to include imagemagick  in android can you provide a good api for image editing having the same number of filters

Comment: don't you feel this is a valid question? My question is genuine since there is no support for Android ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMagick is an open source Java interface of ImageMagick.

Hence it consists of an Java part containing the interface and a binary part containing the actual implementation. As long as you don't find a pre-compiled JMagic binary for Android / ARM architecture you have to compile it yourself.

But in the end this JMagic binary has to be built by the NDK and as it bases on C code it can have memory leaks. Therefore if you want to use ImageMagick/JMagick you have to accept this.

Comment: would you please suggest me any similar Image Editing Libraries for android.